# C# - Revit API - How to debug multi-version Plugin for Revit?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-debugging, revit-api, revit, pyrevit

I'm trying to debug my multi-version plugin for Revit however I'm having issues. It was originally created for Revit 2018 so it debugs fine in that, however when I switch the external program to Revit 2019.ex3, the program runs but none of the breakpoints are being hit.

I currently have 2 different debug configuration files. One for revit 2018 and one for revit 2019 which is what i would imagine the correct path to go.

When I look at the breakpoints while debug is running, I see `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document.`

I've tried loading the matching family symbol file but that when selected, I get the following warning:

[image]

When I look at generating a new .pdb file, I've found that the pdb file that can be used is only the one that was created with this file.

How can I can I enable debugging for both versions in revit?

All help and/or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Configure your project to have separate debug builds e.g. DEBUG2019, DEBUG2020, ... Each build should output the binaries to its own directory e.g. build/debug/2019 Then add manifest files for each version of Revit to these binaries. To debug, build the project, run Revit, attach your debugger to Revit and add breakpoints to stop the process when needed